# Portion of Screen Broke

Tags: laptop, display

A portion of my laptop screen broke. Is there method I can use to resize the screen so that no window appears on the broken part of the screen? It's like 1/6 of the screen on the right that makes anything over there impossible to see.

Comment: may i ask what kind of program you're talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use only part of screen, as if the monitor was a smaller one?](http://superuser.com/questions/129310/how-to-use-only-part-of-screen-as-if-the-monitor-was-a-smaller-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the right video driver, you can configure a custom resolution for the Display control panel that cuts off pixels - eg 1066 x 1024 instead of 1280 x 1024.

Though, this question might be better placed on Super User ... as it's not really a programming problem.

Comment: @Bevan I am now in this same situation, but I don't know if your answer really solves the problem the way Devoted wants.  I personally would like to keep the resolution the *same*, but prevent a portion from being used.  By changing the display resolution, you inevitably end up with jaggies on-screen.

Comment: @Dave - if you have the right video driver, you can go to a custom resolution *without scaling* - effectively you configure a margin of the screen that isn't used, avoiding the damaged part of the screen without introducing jaggies.

Comment: what about shifting the screen real estate?  I haven't seen something like that before.  My current laptop driver does indeed let me avoid rescaling, but then I have to have the contents centered, which still overlaps the damaged region.

Comment: @Dave That's close to what I've seen. With the right video driver (caveat: one might not exist for your particular chipset), you aren't limited to centering your reduced resolution, but can move it to avoid the damaged part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Check GridMove and Sizer at:
http://lifehacker.com/software/productivity/download-of-the-day-gridmove-windows-199404.php and http://lifehacker.com/277753/take-advantage-of-your-widescreen-monitor-with-sizer

Sizer is more manual, Gridmove I think is more automated. I have never tried them yet.