# How to trick windows 7 to use only a part of the screen

Tags: windows, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use only part of screen, as if the monitor was a smaller one?](https://superuser.com/questions/129310/how-to-use-only-part-of-screen-as-if-the-monitor-was-a-smaller-one)

I have a broken 20" LCD monitor which displays random pixels in the top 200 lines of pixels.
I want to limit the display in such a way that when I maximize a window it will not be in the bad area and to limit the cursor position so it won't be in the bad area.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my comments I think this deserve's its own answer.

Create a toolbar

[image: Create a toolbar]

Drag it to the top of the screen and make it as big as you need.

[image: Make it big]

And finally make sure it is "Always on Top"

[image: Always on top]

Simple solution that doesn't require any additional software.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a program called [DesktopCoral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html) which do a similar thing as in the links toolbar but actually  works in Windows 7. Still don't have an idea how to limit the cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what type of monitor you have you can adjust the vertical position and sizing to move it away from the bad area.

You may be able to do this in your video driver, but I can't offer assistance there since you don't list what you are using.

Comment: If I adjust the vertical position and sizing I will move it from the bad area but I'll have the same resolution occupying a smaller space and it would look bad.

Comment: Yup, but that is the only way I can think of to accomplish your goals.  200 pixels is a lot of screen real estate to be missing.  Maybe changing your resolution to a wide screen would look better. Instead of 1280 x 1024 go to 1280 x 800.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to start Magnifier tool and to stick it to the top of your screen (set `Views` to `Docked`).

Note: since it is not possible to completely disable Magnifier view (keep it black), set `Tracking` to `Follow the keyboard focus` to avoid be disturbing each time you move your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stop your programs from using that area (rather than attempting to ensure that the top is not used, ie black), then the simplest way is to put something there and reserve it.

For example,  download the free version of [Object Dock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/) and configure it to display at the top of the screen and to reserve the edge of the screen. You can configure the size of the pixels which should affect the size of the bar.

Comment: You could also add an empty quick launch bar to the top of the screen and make as big as the bad area. http://imgur.com/0NS0J.png http://imgur.com/jEp7F.png

Comment: Dooh!.  Yes that would be much easier and more memory efficient.