# Is it possible to make Windows only use part of my screen?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution, desktop, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to trick windows 7 to use only a part of the screen](https://superuser.com/questions/166948/how-to-trick-windows-7-to-use-only-a-part-of-the-screen)

The left 25% of my display is damaged, and I would like to make Windows not use this damaged portion of the screen (I see no reason to buy a new laptop if the rest of the system is working fine).

I want to effectively decrease the desktop resolution and align it to the right side so it is not affected by the damaged section of the monitor, and make it so that application windows can't be on the damaged portion of the monitor or get lost there.

System Specifications:

Windows 7 Home Premium (x64)
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470

So here my explicit question: Can I resize and relocate the desktop?

Comment: it´s good you´re asking, I have almost the same problem but i´ve got a nvidia graphics card and resizing is no problem but locating is

Comment: An untested idea: maybe you could enable [Remote Desktop](www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/) on your system and then create a Remote Desktop Connection to the enabled server from the same machine. Such connects can be run in a resizable and positionable window.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/166948/how-to-trick-windows-7-to-use-only-a-part-of-the-screen