# How to limit the displayed pixels?

Tags: linux, display, opensuse, pixels

So I recently broke my monitor and now small part of its bottom is blinking and not displaying correctly.

Anyway how could I disable the broken pixels - so that they are not powered? I'm using IPS235. I read the manual and it seems that the only properties that could help me was positioning the picture when in VGA mode (from the monitor menu). But it seems that this option still gives power to the broken pixels and even more - even if we ignore those pixels (maybe place some tape over them so that they are not visible) - I can't move the picture enough that it's not overlapping with them.

I'm running various OSes but currently I'm messing with linux. I have nvidia dirvers for my GPU but I don't know - is there some way I could move the picture displayed to the monitor so that it doesn't overlap with the broken pixels?

I think that the only possible solution to this problem is on the software side because it's seems that the firmware on the monitor is too basic.

So any ideas?

Comment: Posting your video hardware and software might help us.

Comment: Also see this: http://superuser.com/questions/166948/how-to-trick-windows-7-to-use-only-a-part-of-the-screen

Comment: I found the best solution to my problem - on the low level possible. It's called underscan. Tweaked some Nvidia X server settings - and now only the working part of my display is used - I could safe some cash on a new one now - only will need to apply some tape on the blinking pixels and I got an 1920x830 working monitor from my originally 1920x1080 with a cool line marks coming from the top on the left side. That's a bargain bi*h

Comment: @WindowsXpUser you should post that as an answer.