# Splitting one giant monitor as if it was two. Picture in Picture

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, pip

How can I split one giant computer screen into two screens, so I could stream Al Jazeera in fullscreen mode on one side, while I program on the other side?

Or what about adding a PIP -- Picture in Picture -- to your monitor. PIP once was the default way to let your wife watch the Tele without you missing the game.

I know it would give my video card a run for its money, but I think it could work.

Is is possible in either Windows or Linux?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553631/virtual-monitors-on-single-monitor) seems to be pertinent.

Comment: couldn't you just use windows 7's aerosplit option? Neatly cuts your screen in two though not 'fullscreen' proper

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Probably won't work for flash video full screen.

Comment: **Related:** [How to use only part of screen, as if the monitor was a smaller one?](http://superuser.com/questions/129310/how-to-use-only-part-of-screen-as-if-the-monitor-was-a-smaller-one)