# Resize screen virtually (xrandr)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr

The screen of my macbook is broken. The right hand side is black (dead pixels) and so is a small part of the bottom. See image.

[image]

If I watch a movie in full screen, I cannot see right part of the screen. I want to solve this by resizing my screen virtually so that only the part of the screen that is not broken is able to use.

Related: [Limiting desktop size in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/719510/limiting-desktop-size-in-linux)

I tried using xrandr commands in that post, as I'm using Ubuntu, but limiting to 4:3 format is only a start - then I want to position (x,y) coordinates so that it starts in the top left corner. I lack the knowledge for how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --fb 1700x956
```

Then the screen size get limited. This, however, is not exactly what you wish to do. Because with this solution makes it so that the upper left hand corner where the clock is gets *hidden* rather than *moved* see two images below.

[image: enter image description here left]

[image: enter image description here right]