# Use only part of display

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, 4k-resolution

I'm planning to get a 4k 55 inch display for my desktop, since I mostly use it for gaming and watching football. I will however also use it for some other tasks, such as browsing and occasional programming. For these latter tasks having a 55 inch display at an arms length away is not only excessive, but straight out inconvenient.

Since a 4k monitor packs the same amount of pixels as 4 full hd monitors I was thinking that if I could use 1/4 th of the monitor for these tasks that would be enough (preferably vertically and horizontally centered). Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm running Windows 10 and will be buying a midrange GPU along with the new monitor (so if NVIDIA or AMD has a solution, that is of interest).

Note: I have already seen this [old question](https://superuser.com/questions/129310/how-to-use-only-part-of-screen-as-if-the-monitor-was-a-smaller-one), but its outdated.

Note2: I'm aware that a midrange GPU will not allow me to play most recent games in 4k resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows 10 it has a feature called snap assist

> Drag the title bar to the top edge of the screen to maximize a window.
>
> Drag the title bar to the left or right edge of the screen to snap the application to the right or left.
>
> You can also snap apps to any of the four corners by dragging the title bar to those corners.
>
> If you have any other open windows after snapping one window, you will see Snap Assist. This new feature on Windows 10 displays the other apps as thumbnails in the available space. Tap or click one of the thumbnails to snap it in that space.

http://m.windowscentral.com/how-use-snap-assist-windows-10